# Credit card debt

Tags: credit-card, debt-collection, norway, russia

A Russian-Norwegian dual nationality person I know took up 20000 pounds of credit card loans in Norway. He then went back to Russia and has lived there for 1 year now.

He has not heard anything yet. Will they come after him in Russia?

Comment: Does he plan to ever return to Norwegia?

Comment: No, he thinks he must not enter the EU again

Comment: Wait, do you mean he thinks he "should not enter again because of this issue".  Or do you mean, unrelated to this, he will never enter again?